# jQuery code in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I was forced to use jQuery code in Angular to hack a plugin that I need to use; should I put this code in the controller or in a `<script>` tag in the html (to have code that manipulates DOM close to the DOM)?

Comment: Turn it into a directive.

Comment: A controller should never manipulate the DOM, that is the job of a directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better you write your own custom directive. Please follow here at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive.

You should keep the view logic separate either to HTML or to directives. Angular recommends this to keep your business logic separate from view logic.